# iOS app crashing in release but not in development and Swift symbols are not resolved

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My app is working perfectly fine in development but switching to production / AdHoc release it crashes on the transition to the third UIViewController of my application flow.

Between the build there shouldn't be any difference. I have retrieved the log from the Devices window:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000d49ac
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MYAPP                           0x00000001000d49ac 0x100010000 + 805292
1   UIKit                           0x00000001868a8954 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 688
2   UIKit                           0x00000001868a8664 -[UIViewController view] + 28
3   UIKit                           0x0000000186f9c1cc -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 72
4   UIKit                           0x0000000186ba378c -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 116
5   UIKit                           0x0000000186bbeb4c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1968
6   UIKit                           0x0000000186bc0f64 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 116
7   UIKit                           0x0000000186995c48 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 212
8   MYAPP                           0x0000000100090dcc 0x100010000 + 527820
9   MYAPP                           0x0000000100090bd0 0x100010000 + 527312
10  PromiseKit                      0x000000010032a9f4 0x1002e8000 + 272884
11  PromiseKit                      0x00000001002ee820 0x1002e8000 + 26656
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001936c1990 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001936c1950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001936c6208 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1604
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001820522e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182050390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181f7d1f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
18  GraphicsServices                0x000000018b39f6f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKit                           0x000000018690e108 UIApplicationMain + 1484
20  MYAPP                           0x00000001000be820 0x100010000 + 714784
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001936eea04 start + 0
```

What is bugging me:

1. There is a clear inconsistency between the environments I am working on.
2. The calls from MYAPP doesn't seem to be linked to any component / method call. I'm working with Swift maybe it does cause problem to resolve symbols. Which could make sense since PromiseKit calls are also unresolved.
3. I have no idea about how to debug this, not even about how to put log everywhere (because I wouldn't know how to get them).

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `Build settings`, try changing `Swift compiler` -> `Optimization Level` -> `Release` to `None`. There's still a bug where sometimes the compiler messes up closures when optimizations are on. Maybe that's what's happening to you.

Comment: You saved my day. I'm just curious to know how you discovered that.

Comment: I had the same problem with my last app. Turning off the optimization confirmed it was a compiler problem, then someone at the Apple Dev forums confirmed it's still not fixed notably for complex closures and viewcontrollers initializers. In my case, simplifying some expressions in the code and ensuring all the initializers had their `required` parts fixed it, I was able to put the optimizations back on.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway ! I don't need hard performances, so I will survive to the lack of a few optimizations but that's definitely not cool.

Comment: Thanks for this! And thanks @EricAya for linking me here. In my case, with an older Objective-C app, I did a search in Build Settings for "compiler" and found the Optimization Level settings. Confirmed it's a compiler problem, will have to look into simplifying my code to see if the app can be built with optimizations without problem or if I need to leave optimizations turned off.