# Class crashing in production but not debug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following class:

```
    import UIKit

    class HeaderTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var nonDefaultTitle : String?

    var data: [String: [String]] = [:]

    var headers : [String]       = []
    var bodys   : [[String]]     = []

    init(displayData: [String: [String]]) {
        super.init(style: .Grouped)
        data = displayData

        for key in data.keys {
            headers.append(key)
        }

        for arr in data.values {
            bodys.append(arr)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DefaultCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCustomCell")

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50

        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100;

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "HeaderTableHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderTableHeaderView")

        if let ttle = nonDefaultTitle {
            self.title = ttle
        }
        else {
            self.title = "Talking Tips"
        }
    }
}

//
// MARK: Helpers
//
extension HeaderTableViewController {
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return headers.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let body = bodys[section] as [String]

        return body.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("HeaderTableHeaderView")
        let header = cell as? HeaderTableHeaderView
        header!.titleLabel.text = headers[section]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DefaultCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DefaultCustomCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = bodys[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { }
}



//
// MARK: The table headers
//
class HeaderTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}

//
// MARK: Class that handles the HeaderTableLargeHeaderView (sorry for the terrible naming conventions)
//
class HeaderTableLargeHeaderView: UIView {

    // Our title label with autolayout constraints
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    // Convience method to load for xib
    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "HeaderTableLargeHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward. It runs fine if I install via Xcode or AdHoc using Diawi.

If however I install via TestFlight or through the AppStore it crashes every time.... Did I do something wrong here? My device logs give me this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   UIKit                           0x0000000196387a4c __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 424
1   UIKit                           0x00000001963879f0 __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 332
2   UIKit                           0x0000000196347368 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2712
3   UIKit                           0x00000001963467e4 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 536
4   UIKit                           0x0000000196346570 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 60
5   UIKit                           0x00000001963463a4 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 220
6   UIKit                           0x000000019634c918 -[UITableView setContentInset:] + 252
7   UIKit                           0x0000000196320438 -[UIViewController _setNavigationControllerContentInsetAdjustment:] + 428
8   UIKit                           0x000000019632017c -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 464
9   UIKit                           0x0000000196322214 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 160
10  UIKit                           0x0000000196322094 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
11  UIKit                           0x0000000196408a58 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 2076
12  UIKit                           0x0000000196320d74 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 676
13  UIKit                           0x00000001963209dc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
14  UIKit                           0x0000000196320940 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
15  UIKit                           0x0000000196265738 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1196
16  QuartzCore                      0x000000019372e40c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
17  QuartzCore                      0x00000001937230e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
18  QuartzCore                      0x0000000193722fa8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
19  QuartzCore                      0x000000019369fc64 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
20  QuartzCore                      0x00000001936c70d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
21  UIKit                           0x000000019625ae08 _afterCACommitHandler + 324
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001903cd7dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001903cb40c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001903cb89c __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001902fa048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
26  GraphicsServices                0x0000000191d7d198 GSEventRunModal + 180
27  UIKit                           0x00000001962d3818 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
28  UIKit                           0x00000001962ce550 UIApplicationMain + 208
29  Care Com                        0x00000001000db12c 0x1000b4000 + 160044
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018f2dc5b8 start + 4
```

---

So I've been able to track down the issue by switching my run scheme from debug to release. This is the error that's crashing:

```
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8589934592) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

---

So I found what I thought to be the solution however I'm not sure why it works. I was getting the error stated above on this line:

```
bodys[section].count
```

If I turn this:

`Optimization Level: Fast, Single-File Optimization [-0]`

to

`Optimization Level: None [-Onone]`

---

So the above fix works when installed via Xcode and TestFlight, however it crashes when downloaded from the app store...still opening and looking for a fix.

---

I tried changing my `init` method to this:

```
init(displayData: [String: [String]]) {
    super.init(style: .Grouped)

    //data = displayData

    // I get a bad access error thrown when trying to access displayData
    print(displayData)

    for key in displayData.keys {
        headers.append(key)
    }

    for arr in displayData.values {
        bodys.append(arr)
    }
}
```

and turned optimization back on which gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to use the init parameter.

---

I also ran with instruments with out the optimization on to check for leaks and memory allocations and here is what I got. This is the version that is running fine through TestFlight and Xcode but crashing when installed through the AppStore. The red arrows are when I pushed to the views that are crashing in production.

Memory allocations: 
[image]

Leaks:
[image]

---

Here is how I'm instantiating and pushing the view:

```
func testPush() {
    let data = createTestData()

    let tableHeaderVC = HeaderTableViewController(displayData: data as! [String : [String]])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableHeaderVC, animated: true)
}

func createTestData() -> [String : [String]] {
    let firstSection  = ["Row one", "Row two"]
    let secondSection = ["Row one", "Row two"]

    return ["First" : firstSection, "Second" : secondSection]
}
```

---

Also, after looking at this question I thought maybe it was an issue with doing a custom initializer. So I removed that and did it where I set the variable before pushing...still getting the same error with optimization on.

Comment: A malloc error like this feels like a memory leak, usually latent but revealed by the agressive compiler optimizations. // Oh and the "size" is rather big... maybe you actually ran out of available memory. You can use Instruments.app to inspect how the memory behaves in your app.

Comment: @EricAya seems to be the issue...but why would accessing the array count cause this?

Comment: @EricAya thank you so much for helping me with this. I've updated my question to include your suggested try and also running instruments.

Comment: @EricAya that part was the only place that was using `data`. It seems the only way it will work is if I remove the optimization....Which what blows my mind that if I install through TestFlight it works fine. I then use that same build to put into production and it crashes?

Comment: I hear you - it also [happend to me and to this user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29433517/2227743). I was lucky to be able to satisfy the compiler - I hope you'll find a way too.

Comment: By the way, read my comment under the answer - maybe the part about "required initializers" applies to you?

Comment: @EricAya I went to my last resort and submitted a DTS ticket in hopes they can help me :( I think that may be, I guess I could always refactor the class so it doesn't use a custom initializer